# Once sheets are imported, hyperlink is only connecting to one sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, import, hyperlink, spreadsheet

I have a VBA that imports sheets named support in different Excels. The sheet is called support. Once imported into the target workbook, it creates a hyperlink with a name based on the title of the imported Excel file.
The problem is that the link only works for one of the sheets and ignores the rest.
I think this is because when asked which sheet to import, it takes support but then in the targeted workbook, the rest of the sheets are imported as Support (2), support (3), and so on.
Is there a way that I can modify the code?

```vb
Sub ImportSheetsFromFolder()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim selectedFile As Variant
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    ' Prompt user to select folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select Folder Containing Excel Files"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            folderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "No folder selected. Exiting."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Set target workbook (current workbook)
    Set targetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Prompt user for sheet name to import
    sheetName = InputBox("Enter the name of the sheet to import:", "Sheet Name")
    If sheetName = "" Then
        MsgBox "No sheet name provided. Exiting."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Loop through each file in the selected folder
    selectedFile = Dir(folderPath & "\*.xlsx")
    
    Do While selectedFile <> ""
        ' Open source workbook
        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & selectedFile)
        
        ' Check if the sheet exists in the source workbook
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = sourceWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
       
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' If the sheet exists, import it into the target workbook
       
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            ws.Copy After:=targetWorkbook.Sheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        End If
        
        Worksheets("Hyperlink").Select
'        Range("A1").Select <--Remove
       
        ' Create hyperlink for each sheet that was imported into seperate sheet in target WB
'        For Each ws In Worksheets <--Remove
        
        ' Check if the sheet name is not one of the excluded sheets
        If ws.Name <> "TB 460201" And ws.Name <> "Hyperlink" And ws.Name <> "Cover sheet" And ws.Name <> "Supporting details" And ws.Name <> "Data" Then
            ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="" & ws.Name & "!A1" & "", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=sourceWorkbook.Name
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
       
        ' Close the source workbook without saving changes
        sourceWorkbook.Close False
        
        ' Move to the next file
        selectedFile = Dir
         
    Loop
   
    MsgBox "Import complete."
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please fix the code sample in your post so all code is displayed as code

Comment: Thanks, Vbasic2008.  @JKpieterse, fixed

Comment: Once a sheet is copied into the master workbook, it has likely become the active sheet. So you can take it's name from there (use a variable) and then use that variable to set up the hyperlink. Remember to add ' around the worksheet name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. I've also changed the logic a little.

```
Sub ImportSheetsFromFolder()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim selectedFile As Variant
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' Prompt user to select folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select Folder Containing Excel Files"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            folderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "No folder selected. Exiting."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    ' Set target workbook (current workbook)
    Set targetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

    ' Prompt user for sheet name to import
    sheetName = InputBox("Enter the name of the sheet to import:", "Sheet Name")
    If sheetName = "" Then
        MsgBox "No sheet name provided. Exiting."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Loop through each file in the selected folder
    selectedFile = Dir(folderPath & "\*.xlsx")

    Do While selectedFile <> ""
        ' Open source workbook
        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & selectedFile)

        ' Check if the sheet exists in the source workbook
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = sourceWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)

        On Error GoTo 0

        ' If the sheet exists, import it into the target workbook

        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            ws.Copy After:=targetWorkbook.Sheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
            Dim newSheetName As String
            ' Close the source workbook without saving changes
            sourceWorkbook.Close False
            newSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
            Worksheets("Hyperlink").Select
            '        Range("A1").Select <--Remove

            ' Create hyperlink for each sheet that was imported into seperate sheet in target WB
            '        For Each ws In Worksheets <--Remove

            ' Check if the sheet name is not one of the excluded sheets
            If newSheetName <> "TB 460201" And newSheetName <> "Hyperlink" And newSheetName <> "Cover sheet" And newSheetName <> "Supporting details" And newSheetName <> "Data" Then
                ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & newSheetName & "'!A1" & "", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=selectedFile
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If

        End If

        ' Move to the next file
        selectedFile = Dir

    Loop

    MsgBox "Import complete."

End Sub
```